# Zend SQL statement to find and order results by occurances

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework

I have a table which looks like this:

```
ID | name | phone_number | date
1  | bob  | 4567         | 1/1/2011
2  | bob  | 8912         | 1/1/2010
3  | bob  | 1234         | 1/1/2010
4  | bob  | 1234         | 1/1/2014
5  | bow  | 4567         | 1/1/2014
```

I am creating an auto suggest so as a user types a name it will pick up previous names and phone numbers. As people can change their number, I want to order the results and display a count of the numbers based on the most popular phone number. As a second sort it should be based on the name and a final sort on the date it was added (newest first).

So if someone types 'bo' it should return:

```
bob 1234 (2) - Because it is alphabetically highest plus has the most phone numbers.
bob 4567 (1) - Because it is alphabetically highest and its last entry is newer.
bob 8912 (1) - Because it is alphabetically highest and its last entry was older.
bow 4567 (1) - Because it is alphabetically lower.
```

Normally I would use the Zend methods for example:

```
public function getAllNames($part)
{
    $select = $this->select();
    $select->where('name LIKE ?', '%'.$part.'%')
           ->order('name');
    return $this->fetchAll($select)->toArray();
}
```

But I am stuck on how to count the entries for phone numbers and then perform the three orders.

OR is it better to just get all the entries and use PHP to process the results and order them accordingly?

Comment: I'm SQL. I don't know what a 1/1/2011 is. :-(

Comment: Sorry, the table is kinda made up, a human representation (so are the dates..) for the purpose of the question, the dates are timestamps in the real DB ;-)

Comment: Human? So people who don't subscribe to your date format aren't human ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about following?

```
public function getAllNames($part)
{
   $select = $this->select();
   $select->where('name LIKE ?', '%'.$part.'%')
          ->order('name')
          ->order(new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('LENGTH(phone_number)'))
          ->order('date desc');
   return $this->fetchAll($select)->toArray();
}
```

**UPDATED ANSWER**

```
public function getAllNames($part)
{
   $select = $this->select();
   $select->where('name LIKE ?', '%'.$part.'%')
          ->group('name')
          ->group('phone_number')
          ->order('name')
          ->order(new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('count(phone_number) DESC'))
          ->order(new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('max(date) DESC'));
   return $this->fetchAll($select)->toArray();
}
```

**Another UPDATE: using max(date) is not necessary**

```
public function getAllNames($part)
{
   $select = $this->select();
   $select->where('name LIKE ?', '%'.$part.'%')
          ->group('name')
          ->group('phone_number')
          ->order('name')
          ->order(new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('count(phone_number) DESC'))
          ->order('date DESC');
   return $this->fetchAll($select)->toArray();
}
```

Comment: Would that not just be trying to order on the number of characters in the phone number? Also it would not stop duplicates being returned?

Comment: oh, yeah, i misunderstood 'most telephone numbers', kind of silly, was wondering what the purpose was... let me get back to you on this :)

Comment: Ok, corrected the answer, I made a quick test case and it seems to return the right results... hope this help ;)

Comment: Ok this didn't quite work for me, as I don't have the Zend\Db\Sql\Expression part. But it did show me the way to go. Used the groups to remove duplicates. And added a from statement, and added columns, which meant I could create the count column, and then order by that! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer I have actually used thanks to user3511578. As in the comments, I don't have the expression module in my zend library, so I did it like this:

*Just in case it helps anyone in the future:*

```
public function getAllNames($part)
{
    $select = $this->select();
    $select->from($this->_name, array('name', 'phone_number', 'count'=>'COUNT(phone_number)'))
           ->where('name LIKE ?', '%'.$part.'%')
           ->group('name')
           ->group('number')
           ->order('name')
           ->order('count DESC')
           ->order('date desc');
    return $this->fetchAll($select)->toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly...

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

 CREATE TABLE my_table
 (ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
 ,name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
 ,phone_number VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
 ,date DATE NOT NULL
 );

 INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
 (1  ,'bob','4567','2011-01-01'),
 (2  ,'bob','8912','2010-01-01'),
 (3  ,'bob','1234','2010-01-01'),
 (4  ,'bob','1234','2014-01-01'),
 (5  ,'bow','4567','2014-01-01');


 SELECT x.*
      , y.total
   FROM my_table x
   JOIN
      ( SELECT name
             , phone_number
             , MAX(date) n_date
             , COUNT(*) total
          FROM my_table
         WHERE name LIKE 'bo%'
         GROUP
            BY name
             , phone_number
      ) y
     ON y.name = x.name
    AND y.phone_number = x.phone_number
    AND y.n_date = x.date
  ORDER
     BY x.name
      , y.total DESC
      , x.date DESC;
 +----+------+--------------+------------+-------+
 | ID | name | phone_number | date       | total |
 +----+------+--------------+------------+-------+
 |  4 | bob  | 1234         | 2014-01-01 |     2 |
 |  1 | bob  | 4567         | 2011-01-01 |     1 |
 |  2 | bob  | 8912         | 2010-01-01 |     1 |
 |  5 | bow  | 4567         | 2014-01-01 |     1 |
 +----+------+--------------+------------+-------+
```